# How To Set A Timer On An Element To Fade Out And Reset The Timer If The Element Is Clicked Open

Tags: javascript

I have  a cookie popup in place which I need to fade in when the page loads after 5 seconds and if the popup is clicked it opens and the timer to be reset.. here is what I have so far.

```
function cookiePopup(){
            var $cookie_popup = $("#cookie_popup");
            words = $cookie_popup.children('p').text().split(' ').length;
            alert(words);
            $cookie_popup.fadeIn(200).delay(words*200+3000).fadeOut(function()
            {$(this).remove();
            });
            $cookie_popup.children("#cookie_close").on("click",function(){
                $cookie_popup.hide().remove;
            });
        }
```

Comment: What's not working as expected?

Comment: I can't get it to reset the delay if its open.. when the page loads the popup bar appears and after 5 seconds fades out but when you click it so it expands the timer is continuing from the page load. I want to give the user a chance to read the cookie info when its expanded.  It currently does everything I need im just stuck on getting the timer to reset when the cookie info is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
var timeout = setTimeout( createPopup, 5000 );

function createPopup() {
    clearTimeout( timeout );

    // .. popup creation code ..
}

something.onclick = createPopup;
```

Comment: @zk13: Here's an example using your code and setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/786EX/1/

Comment: @Jop, thanks! Only thing is that you don't need an extra function wrapper in setTimeout. createPopup is already a function. But it's minor.